# Display sidebars after the main content in mobile view

Tags: html, css, layout

I am working with a legacy website with older design that uses two vertical menu sidebars, one to the left and one to the right of the main content.  On narrow screens, such as in mobile view, the sidebar divs are displayed before the main content.  I want them to drop to the bottom of the page, after the main content div.

I realize this can be easily done with flexbox, but there are too many parent and container divs, and I don't want to break anything.  Re-designing the whole site is beyond the scope of this assignment.

Is there a way in CSS to force these two divs to the bottom of their container, without changing the properties of any of the parent divs?

**Edit:** Alternatively, pushing the content div to the top in mobile view would possibly also work.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with css using `position: relative` on elements, and a left property with a negative value on left sidebar 'https://jsfiddle.net/bdp1rhvq/5/. Also it can be done with JS too.

```
<div id='wrapper'>

  <div id='content'>
    content
  </div>

  <div id='sidebar-left'>
    sidebar-left
  </div>

  <div id='sidebar-right'>
    sidebar-right
  </div>

</div>


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
}

#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
  float: left;
  background: #FF5733;
}

#sidebar-left {
  width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
  float: left;
  background: #00cc99;
}

#sidebar-right {
  width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
  float: left;
  background: #cc66ff;
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {

  #wrapper,
  #content,
  #sidebar-left,
  #sidebar-right {
    position: relative;
  }

  #sidebar-right {
    width: 25%;
    right: 0;
  }

  #sidebar-left {
    width: 25%;
    left: -50%;
  }

  #content {
    width: 50%;
    left: 25%;
  }
}
```